# Is it necessary to use embedded Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning *The Ruby on Rails Tutorial* and currently going through the sections on embedded Ruby for the html (.html.erb) files. Is it necessary to use embedded Ruby in the html files? Are there major advantages besides code reusability? I'm trying to simply the learning process as much as I can and I'd like to skip the embedded Ruby/html parts if possible.

Comment: Sure it's *possible* to skip the embedded Ruby part, if you only want to write   some static HTML pages. But what's the point of using Rails then?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's necessary. Otherwise you will have a very hard time displaying dynamic content on your website.

The ERB code pulls data that you set up in your controller and displays that on the page. Don't be afraid of ERB. It's basically just plain Ruby surrounded by a couple tags to isolate from the HTML code. If you don't use ERB you will have to come up with some other way to display your dynamic content. So either way you will have to learn something that can pull data from your database and output dynamic HTML code. For Rails ERB is the chosen syntax.

Comment: Got it. I think I misunderstood the full functionality of ERB and how it fit in with the rest of the Rails framework. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Then why use Rails? The whole point is to generate dynamic pages, and the only way you can make your views dynamic is by mixing in a programming language. ERB does just that. Thankfully, ERB is pretty much plain old Ruby:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end

# app/views/posts/index.html.slim
<ul>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <li><%= post.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

# which is remarkably similar to the following...
output = "<ul>"
@posts.each do |post|
  output << "<li>#{post.title}</li>"
end
output << "</ul>"
```

Unless you're planning to treat Rails like a JSON API and run a JavaScript application, you'll have to buckle down and learn ERB.

Aside from Rails, ERB can come in handy for tons of other situations where you need to fill a text template of some sort with data too.